# Open a range of TCP ports in Cisco IOS NAT

Tags: cisco, tcp, nat

```
ip nat inside source static 192.168.1.10 10.10.10.9 route-map RANGE
!
route-map RANGE permit 100
  match ip address 102
!
access-list 102 permit tcp host 192.168.1.10 range 3000 3389 any
```

The configuration does not seem to work.. just creates a one to one static NAT...

Does any one know how to open range of ports?

I have multiple external IPs and would like to open same ports for multiple hosts using multiple external ip's and because of that the rotary method does not work.

Comment: don't forget to also check ACLs or firewall rules on your external facing interfaces!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 9):

(EDIT)

It seems that inside->outside works as expected, as seen in the answer below, but outside->inside actually does not, it allows everything, as OP suggested.

Adding 'reversible' in the NAT line it starts to honor the route-map for outside->inside, unfortunately it does not seem to work with ports:

1. permit ip any host 194.100.7.226 **works**
2. permit tcp any any **works**
3. permit tcp any any eq 80 **no match, does not work**
4. permit tcp any eq 80 any **match, does not work**
5. permit tcp any eq 80 host 194.100.7.226 **match, does not work**
6. permit tcp any eq 0 host 194.100.7.226 **works**

At '194.100.7.226' I'm doing 'telnet 91.198.120.222 80', that is my source is 194.100.7.226:ephemeral destination is 91.198.120.222:80. As the example **#1** works, we can conclude that *reversible* actually 'reverses' the ACL, so that it works in same manner both directions, which makes sense.

When the the connection match but does not work, in 'deny any any log-input line I get this:

> .Jul  7 07:58:59.118 UTC: %SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGP: list MOO denied tcp
>   91.198.120.2(0) (Tunnel101 ) -> 194.100.7.226(0), 1 packet

So it really seems like L4 protocol type is carried, but ports are not carried during the NAT reversal. So outside->inside ranges do not work.

---

As suggested in question [Cisco 867 forward UDP port range](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/998/cisco-867-forward-udp-port-range) this works for outside->inside

```
ip nat pool MOO 91.198.120.2 91.198.120.2 prefix-length 30 type rotary
ip nat inside destination list MOO pool MOO
ip access-list extended MOO
 permit tcp any any range 22 100
 deny   ip any any log-input
```

It's bit ghetto I feel, as you don't have good control on the outside IP. Pool is the inside IP, outside IP is router outside IP.

---

Original answer of inside->outside working with ports:

```
ip nat inside source static 91.198.120.2 91.198.120.222 route-map MOO
!
ip access-list extended MOO
 permit icmp any any
 permit tcp any any range 22 telnet
!
route-map MOO permit 100
 match ip address MOO
!
route-map MOO deny 200
!
```

@91.198.120.2 I'm doing:

- telnet testhost 22
- telnet testhost 23
- telnet testhost 24

At testhost I can observe:

```
1   0.000000 91.198.120.222 -> 194.100.7.226 TCP 74 50925 > ssh [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1350 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=7995067 TSecr=0 WS=128

2   9.838471 91.198.120.222 -> 194.100.7.226 TCP 74 41586 > telnet [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1350 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=7997586 TSecr=0 WS=128

5  16.773181 91.198.120.2 -> 194.100.7.226 TCP 74 53307 > 24 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1350 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=7999327 TSecr=0 WS=128
```

Tested on:

```
bu.ip.fi#sh ver | i ^Cisco
Cisco IOS Software, C880 Software (C880DATA-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.1(2)T5, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Cisco 881G (MPC8300) processor (revision 1.0) with 236544K/25600K bytes of memory.
bu.ip.fi#
```

Answer (score 1):

so to fix my issue what i did was

```
ip nat inside source static 91.198.120.2 91.198.120.222 route-map MOO
!
ip access-list extended MOO
 permit icmp any any
 permit tcp any any range 22 telnet
!
route-map MOO permit 100
 match ip address MOO
!
```

and i also included an access list 199 on my external interface

```
access-list 199 permit tcp any host external_host eq 3389
access-list 199 deny   ip any host external_host
```

this access list takes care of the allowing all port issue.

Comment: I was worried OP wanted to direct external n1-n2 to host1 and external n3-n4 to host2, which would preclude ACL in external. I wonder if the L4 ports SHOULD work in above example, if it's bug or intended behavior, particularly as it clearly is not 'standard' ACL, as it differentiates UDP and TCP, just ports are '0'.

Comment: how would you use route map to map port 3389 to lets say 90001